# How to convert streaming Dataset[String] to Dataset[Array[String]]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert Dataframe to Dataset of Array of Strings in a streaming query. Trying following approach

```
           DF
            .toJSON
            .write
            .format("org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "brokers")
            .option("topic", "topicname")
            .save()
```

Current Output is

```
{'col1':valuex , 'col2':'value2'}
{'col1':valuey , 'col2':'value3'}
{'col1':valuez , 'col2':'value4'}
{'col1':value1 , 'col2':'value5'}
```

Desired Output is

```
[{'col1':valuex , 'col2':'value2'},{'col1':valuey , 'col2':'value3'},{'col1':valuez , 'col2':'value4'},{'col1':value1 , 'col2':'value5'}]
```

I want to reduce my dataframe size from let say i have 5 string rows in dataset[string] , so it should be reduced to 1 single count which will have array of 5 strings ?

Comment: if the input has 1million rows, do u want to put all of them into one array? isnt there a criteria?

Comment: Hi ravi, I understand, so this will have very few rows actually I am already doing some transformation on this and reducing the data like taking distinct rows only for particular field. So having million rows is not the issue actually . the only concern is I don't want again to form like a stream of rows in kafka so if i want to club them into an array before sending to kafka

Comment: Could you please tell us how is your original json is generated ? thanks

Comment: original i was getting rows like ['value1','value2','value3'] but when i put df.tojson it converted my data into json strings so now i want to club them inside dataframe to form array of strings

Comment: Any suggestions ? @dnej , you understood or should I explain in more detail . In some terms I want to convert my dataset[String] - 5 string rows into dataset[Array[string]] - 1 array. So in short output count of Dataset should be 1 should be

Comment: Could you add the schema of your dataframe please ?

Comment: @dnej - my schema is [col1: int, col2: string]. Also, I have resolved the issue , will share it , I grouped the content and used aggregated function as and collected as list so that way it got converted into Dataframe[Array[String]]

Comment: Could you post your answer please ? Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yes I have shared my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code seems to work just fine.

```
         DF
          .toJSON
          .withColumn("timestamp", lit(System.currentTimeMillis()))
          .groupBy("timestamp").agg(collect_list('value) as 'value)
          .toJSON
          .write
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "...")
          .option("topic", "...")
          .save
```

Comment: You should be using [current_timestamp](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) standard function instead.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski - Yes, but overall is it a fine approach for my use case ? and using current_timestamp function will have any performance impact ? I mean as a coding practice i should use this but overall will it have any other impact also ?

Comment: I think it's OK for your use case.